# Does Elmah run into race condition when 2 session write to the same log file simultaneously?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, logging, elmah

I am developing with ASP.NET MVC, and I am considering using Elmah.

My concern is :
When 2 users visit my site and trigger a logging event (write to a logger file) simultaneously, will Elmah use something like reader/writer lock to handle race condition in the session level(other than thread level)?

Comment: Best thing to do would be to post some code so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The default file-based logging mechanism used by `ELMAH` is to create an `.xml` file per error - presumably to bypass locking issues writing to the same file.

If logging to the db, the default behaviour will be to lock the db table to write, but such a thing will be a split millisecond event and on the rare occasions your app triggers simultaneous errors it will be a simple queue-based scenario (not a race).

I've used ELMAH for many years, it's simple, very useful and well, just works.